# Graphics Tablet as input device for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Having used Windows 8 (and 8.1) on a touch screen I know how much better it is than with a mouse.

I've seen people with graphics tables on 7 use them to scroll their browser etc... so I was wondering if I could use one as a touch screen for windows? and if did would the 8 features of swipe in from the sides etc... work properly?

Just incase brand is an issue in this I was looking at getting a Wacom.